# Adding auto update features to the flex mobile application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4.5, flex-mobile

currently i am working in mobile application development in flex4.5 . i want to know whether there is any possibility to make the auto update feature(regarding the verison) in mobile application using flex 4.5 . please suggest me on this requirement and if there is any possibility please suggest me the code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: +1, I also have similar question..

Answer (score 3):

if you are building application for android platform - 
update the version number of your app in manifest file -

```
<versionNumber>0.5</versionNumber>
```

and upload it, android marketplace will automatically notify the user to update apps, if he is connected to internet and launches apps.